# JavaScript get dimensions of image, not rendered image size

Tags: javascript

How do I get the dimensions of the image that are **not** the *rendered* dimensions of the element displaying the image?

An example of something that will not work...

```
<img onload="alert(this.height);" src="1.png" style="max-height: 50%; max-width: 50%;" />
```

This issue occurs when specifying `max-height` and/or `max-width` which are neccesary. Other methods such as `getComputedStyle` will only determine the dimensions of the rendered image. No frameworks.

Comment: You should try loading the image into a hidden div, where the height and width are not specified.  Then grab the dimensions from how it renders with no override.

Comment: [`naturalHeight`](http://help.dottoro.com/ljqqtiks.php) & [`naturalWidth`](http://help.dottoro.com/ljavxihg.php)

Comment: @durbnpoisn That would work but it is cheap, my skills don't improve from cheap. I don't need expensive though I aim for affordable.

Comment: @Dr.Molle Please post as an answer and I'll accept it, thanks!

Comment: Note that [`naturalHeight`/`naturalWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement) aren't supported in all browsers.

Comment: I don't see it as "cheap" exactly.  You have to download the image before you can get the properties of it.  So you may as well download it raw and take a look at it.

Comment: @André Dion: do you know a common browser that didn't support it(also Opera  supports it, although the linked page says that it doesn't). Basically there are only a few things that are supported by all browsers, e.g. Javascript is not supported by IE2

Comment: @Dr.Molle < IE 9 still holds a significant portion of the browser market.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with **Dr.Molle** get `img` and use `img.naturalWidth` and `img.naturalHeight`.

But there is also another way: set `style` after grabbing natural dimensions:

```
<script>
    function grabNatDims(im) {
        console.log(im.width, im.height);
        im.style.maxHeight = '50%'; im.style.maxWidth = '50%';
    }
</script>
<img onload="grabNatDims(this)" src="1.png">
```